# Is there a way to use Flutter Flavors and use that mechanism to set the --dart-define variables

Tags: flutter, android-flavors, dart-define

With Flutter I use `-dart-define` in order set some environment variables for different API's I use in the flutter app. And I am able to retrieve them using `String.fromEnvironment`.
I also use Flavors in order to set different App icons for both IOS and Android.
This works fine but I end up with a very long build string e.g.

`flutter build ipa --flavor=prod --dart-define BASE_URL=https://example-prod.com/ --dart-define API_PATH=/api/v2/ --dart-define OTHERVAR=blablabla --dart-define YETANOTHERVAR=blablablabla`

What I am looking for is a way where I can type `flutter build ipa --flavor-prod` and a script or configuration setting (in gradle or xcconfig ... or another way) will also set the correct values for the `--dart-define` variables.

I've read a few articles and come across a few people asking the same thing, but I haven't found a proper answer. Most of them will answer that you can pick up the --dart-define values in the build script to get for example the AppName and use that in the build scripts, but I want it the other way around. e.g. If flavor=prod then -dart-define BASE_URL=https://example-prod.com

Comment: I have exactly the same question. I would like the flavor to tell which env variables to use. Having the two flags, --flavor & --dart-define might be prone to errors since the might not match

Comment: I figured it out on iOS but I am stuck on Android

Answer (score 0):

It is not a direct answer in the way that we both want it to be possible, and not 100% ideal because it is a package, but I found a way that we can find out which flavour was built. Using the package

`import 'package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart';`

We can see the bundle identifier (i.e. com.example.app.prod, com.example.app.dev) and therefore we can decide which configuration to load. If `dev` and `prod` are build flavours then they will be appended to the end of the `packageName`.

```dart
          if (Platform.isAndroid) {
            PackageInfo.fromPlatform().then((value) {
              if (value.packageName == "com.example.app.dev") {
                // load dev config
              } else if (value.packageName == "com.example.app.prod") {
                // load prod config
              }
            });
          }
```